# javascript bind does work for function in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

so I have a function inside a dictionary

```
const Dict = {
    func : () => {
       console.log(this);
    }
}

class A {
    constructor() {
        this.fun = Dict.func.bind(this);
    }
}

const a = new A();
a.fun();
```

this gives me undefined, where I'm expecting this to be `a`

this binding seems to work if I move the function out of the dictionary. why doesn't bind work with dictionary?

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind` does not work for `this` with arrow functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function as a property instead of using an arrow function, bind doesn't work for this with arrows

```
const Dict = {
  func() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.fun = Dict.func.bind(this);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.fun();
```